# Fullcalendar: How to send the selected month as parameter in event source?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to get specific data for selected month in  [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)  through ajax. For that I am trying to send date of the selected month as parameter.

Below is what I've tried

```
eventSources: [
        {
            url: '/events/data',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                cur_date: $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate')
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert('Failed);
            },
            allDay : true,   
            rendering : 'background',   
            textColor: '#000' 
        }
]
```

I keep getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Edit: Sending start date and end date of the current view would suffice too

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed fullCalendar will already automatically append the start and end date as query parameters in the request. You should be able to see this if you watch your request in the browser's network tools. there's no need to do anything else to add the date.

Comment: Hi @Mahadi, could you provide the minimal code that reproduces the problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi guys, I've already solved it. All I had to do is send "intervalStart" & "intervalDate" properties as data parameter from the "getView" object (`$('#Fullcalendar').fullCalendar('getView').intervalStart`). Thanks for responding.
@Adyson that seems to work only for GET method

Comment: No, query parameters can be attached to any type of HTTP method. It should work in all circumstances.